# One flask with multiple page

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to be able to change page with my flask when I press on a link

app.py

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/signUp')
def login():
    return render_template('signUp.html')

@app.route('/home')
def login():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <a id ="img_nav" href="{{ url_for('home')}}"><img src = "{{ url_for('static', filename= 'images/UVM_LOGO.jpg') }}" alt="UVM logo" class = "left"></a>
    <nav id= "nav_grid">
        <section class="nav_section">
          <a  href="{{ url_for('login')}}" class="right">Log In</a>
          <a  href="{{ url_for('signUp')}}" class="right">Sign Up</a>
        </section>
    </nav>


    <body>
        <main>
            <h1>Home</h1>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

signUp.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <a id ="img_nav" href="{{ url_for('home')}}"><img src = "{{ url_for('static', filename= 'images/UVM_LOGO.jpg') }}" alt="UVM logo" class = "left"></a>
    <nav id= "nav_grid">
        <section class="nav_section">
          <a  href="{{ url_for('login')}}" class="right">Log In</a>
          <a  href="{{ url_for('signUp')}}" class="right">Sign Up</a>
        </section>
    </nav>


    <body>
        <main>
            <h1>signUp</h1>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <a id ="img_nav" href="{{ url_for('home')}}"><img src = "{{ url_for('static', filename= 'images/UVM_LOGO.jpg') }}" alt="UVM logo" class = "left"></a>
    <nav id= "nav_grid">
        <section class="nav_section">
          <a  href="{{ url_for('login')}}" class="right">Log In</a>
          <a  href="{{ url_for('signUp')}}" class="right">Sign Up</a>
        </section>
    </nav>


    <body>
        <main>
            <h1>login</h1>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error I get is : AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: login

How to I create a flask with a website that has many webpages,
Thank you!

How to I fix it thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used the function name `login` for all of your other routes.

This is causing Flask to be unable to create all your routes because the same name is being overridden multiple times.

Rename your functions for `/login`, `/signUp` and `/home`.

Answer (score 1):

Also you probably not want the links for "Log in" and "Sign up" to link to `/` (index).

Change them to `url_for('login')` (if you decide to name the function for `/login` as `def login:`). The same thing of course for "Sign up".

Check here for reference on how to use `url_for`: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_url_building.htm

Comment: It seems the questions has been changed meanwhile, so this answer isn't valid anymore.